# Transparent images takes emission color

Tags: materials, transparency

Trying to have some nice cut out trees rendered in Evee but having no luck till now.
The images are rendered black in Evee, I can change color of the image if I change the emission color but I can't have the original color of the image. I tried to change format of the image: png, targa, exr. Nothing changed. Here a screenshot of material nodes.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feed the color output of the image texture into the Emission input of the Principled Shader.  That will cause the Principled Shader to use the image as the emission color of the trees.

Comment: Oh it seems banal now. Thank you

Comment: You can place a math node between the image and the emission node, set it to multiply and use a multiplier less than 1 to make it darker; or you can try using rgb curves to adjust.  Pretty much any manipulation can be done between the two.

Comment: Good to know, images were lighter, but it was depending on exposure set too high.